# Update Input value automatically

Tags: html, jquery

In Simple words i want whenever I input value it automatically update current its only update when i Increase/Decrease value in quantity but also want to update automatically quantity when i Increase/Decrease value in result field

**Quantity field where I will input**

```
<input type="number" id="Quantity" value="1" min="1" step="0.01" aria-label="quantity" name="quantity">
```

**This will be always fixed value**

```
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="5">
```

**Result feild:**

```
  <input id="tiles" type="number" name="Tiles" maxlength="12"  value="">
```

**Current JS Code**

```
$("#input2,#Quantity").on('keyup change', function () {

    $('#tiles').val($('#Quantity').val() * $('#input2').val());
                      

});
```

Comment: Can you provide Js fiddle showing your issue ? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: @QuentinRoger please dont ask users to provide a jsfiddle or codepen when the first step should be a [repro]. Questions must by self-containing and not relay on external resources ax explained here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/ and here: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3nbyt2oz/ I don't fully understand your goal ... sorry

Comment: @Frnak Thanks for the response I already achieved this. Now I want if i increase value in result field so automaticaly update one of my input feild which is quantity. Because one is  input is always fixed value and I'm multipling Quantity and fixed input value to get result so quantity and result is changing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this to your js:

```
$("#tiles").on('input', function () {
    $('#Quantity').val($('#tiles').val() / $('#input2').val());                    
});
```

Full example:

```js
$("#input2,#Quantity").on('input', function () {
    $('#tiles').val($('#Quantity').val() * $('#input2').val());                
});

$("#tiles").on('input', function () {
    $('#Quantity').val($('#tiles').val() / $('#input2').val());               
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="Quantity" value="1" min="1" step="0.01" aria-label="quantity" name="quantity">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="5">
<input id="tiles" type="number" name="Tiles" maxlength="12"  value="">
```

EDIT: changed the keyup change to input as suggested by connexo

Comment: Use `input` event instead of `keyup change`. It does exactly what is needed here.

Comment: I know it seems that the community sometimes behaves like a "bully" but it's important to realize that we just want to help. And many times the questions are simply not complete enough or show very low effort while expecting the community to write the code for you. Please beware - none of us is being payed to resolve your issues. Take time to write up high quality questions with very clear problem descriptions and you will receive very nice answers.  Very often I see myself being annoyed by questions where very obviously key information is missing.